# Can I share a music file from my Android device?

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

As part of an application I'm building, I want to publish an audio file from the SD card of an Android device on my wall or the wall of a Facebook friend. Is this possible?

Comment: This is not android support forum. This community is mainly for any programming issues.

Comment: No. I wanted to create an application that allows me to do that

Comment: I didn't even notice we're not on the android.stackexchange. 
Can anyone move this question ?

Comment: I am sorry to not clarify that I thought it is evident:)

Comment: That's a pretty smart idea, but making an app to share directly from your phone to a Facebook wall is a terrible idea - you'll run into many problems, specially if you're phone is off the internet. I do believe it would be best to use a hosting site like TomS said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know the simplest way you can do this is using some sort of web interface and connect your Android directly to the web.

Get [FILE EXPERT](https://market.android.com/details?id=xcxin.filexpert&hl=en) (it's free on the market) it has an option of 'sharing my contents' - 'start share via web'

The app will give you and IP address that anyone can connect and access your phone contents via browser.

You can also set different users and allow them to see specific files.

In this case, you'll need to set up your router to have port forwarding to the phone or find a way to connect the phone directly to the internet.

The other option is setting up a SAMBA server or a FTP server, but I believe that you'll want a simple and practical solution.

But remember, as noted by TomS, you're phone would've to be online while the file is shared. As soon as you're out of battery or off the web the file is out.

I still believe that a hosting website would be the best solution.

BTW:

I just realized that FILE EXPERT has a 'My Cloud' option that you can send your files directly yo box.net/dropbox/kanbox and Sina Vdisk.

It seems to manage your account - but then again, I haven't tried it out yet.

Comment: Although possible you should also point out the negative aspects to this solution, like the content only being accessible as long as the smartphone is connected to the web, and the security aspects that arise of enabling anyone to access files directly on your device.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I recognize that the task is difficult, if facebook allows me I can send it to my facebook friends through the attachments but I think it is impossible to send facebook message, can you confirm it, otherwise would be possible to go through dro...

Comment: You can share the dropbox file address - I just tried sending it via message and it worked fine. I'm not sure you can share on your wall, but I can't think of any good reason for not being able to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible. You'll have to upload the file to somewhere on the web and then share the link to it.

There are several file hosting sites you can use.

Comment: Is there any cloud solution with API to upload then download the file ??

Comment: After searching for a little bit I can't seem to find any API or library to upload files to any file hosting site. But if you're trying to share audio clips then you might consider using Soundcloud, which does provide an Android toolkit: https://github.com/soundcloud/android-intent-sharing/wiki

Comment: @zabab Dropbox has an API as far as I remember. You could upload there and post the link wherever you want

Comment: @barry, Thanks, I totally forgot about dropbox.